# Python class method merge

Tags: python, class, inheritance

Is it possible to merge two classes' methods like so?

```
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active = False
    def doThing(self):
        if not self.active: return
        print("Just a foo here, boss")

class bar(foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.active = False
    def doThing(self):
        print("I shouldn't be showing unless I'm active!")

f = foo()
b = bar()
f.doThing()
b.doThing()
```

This will output "I shouldn't be showing unless I'm active!" when I want it to inherit the self.active checking part of the parent class and thus make the method return before the rest of it runs. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the check in a separate function:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active = False

    def isActive(self):
        return self.active

    def doThing(self):
        if not self.isActive(): return
        print("Just a Foo here, boss")

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def doThing(self):
        if not self.isActive(): return
        print("I shouldn't be showing unless I'm active!")
```

Or alternative:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.active = False

    def doThing(self):
        if not self.active: return
        return self.doPrint()

    def doPrint(self):
        print("Just a Foo here, boss")

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def doPrint(self):
        print("I shouldn't be showing unless I'm active!")
```

Comment: I like the alternative here. You restructured the code so the OOP application makes sense. OP take notes, a lot of the times, correct code is logically intuitive. Incorrect OOP code will seem logically incongruent. Class design is key in OOP programming.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct, merging the functions does not make any sense. Though if you want to implement the second class and merge it in an OOP manner, the code is below.

```
class Bar(Foo):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

def doThing(self):
    super(self).doThing()
    if not self.isActive(): return
    print("I shouldn't be showing unless I'm active!")
```

Comment: Note that the above code is redundant, checking for the active condition is done twice. It is an example of bad OOP design which creates redundant code.